# Optimizing using statements in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

While I was doing a code test on Codility, I had created a project in visual studio so I could just copy in the solution when I was done.

However, while `using System;` was enough in VS to get the project running, it would not compile on the website unless I added `using System.Collections.Generic;` as well.

How do I optimize my using statement to be more specific so that they will compile on Codility?

Answer (score 2):

If your VS project is targeting a recent .NET version, it will have implicit usings enabled by default, which may well be the problem; try explicitly disabling this feature, by (in the csproj, in a `<PropertyGroup>`) adding:

```xml
<ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However I have already tried this and I still have the same problem.

I remember when I was using Eclipse for Java development. There was a shortcut key to split your generic import into many, more specific imports...

Comment: If this didn't work for you, post your `.csproj` file and your code file here.